# Image isn't viewable after hosting my website github

Tags: html, image, github, host

I recently began learning web developing, after hosting my website to git hub, the image isn't viewable instead shows as attached with the image description.

The code is (    
it works fine on vs code.

Appreciate your help with that

I moved the picture to different location, added the changed the width, and length of it, yet still didn't work

Comment: can you share image tag code. the location where the image is present.

Comment: Your question seems to get asked here, and all over the internet, every hour. The solution is always the same. Your path namei s wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check your path of the image and the path you gave in the code.

```
<img src="your_path"/>
```

If the path is different, just edit the path with the new one and commit the file. That's it! It should work.

If it still not working, check the file extension...